# Word to describe something difficult to remember?

Tags: single-word-requests

This would be used when someone has to memorize certain information, but the nature of that information is difficult to grasp and recollect or a large set of numbers. Is there a particular word for these?

Comment: My suggestion: "memory-demanding"

Comment: Let’s see, I used to know it ...

Comment: There is no single word for this. You need to say something like "a long list of apparently random data".

Comment: @Jim -  I had an answer similar to yours but I can't remember what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is somewhat broadly focused on both memory and comprehension. Addressing "***difficult to grasp or recollect***" as in the first example, a thing that is difficult to remember in that way can be referred to as "**elusive**".

Referring then to "***a large set of numbers***", as in the second example, a word for difficult to remember due to size or volume (i.e. a large list or long passage of text) is a "**challenge**". It can be a "*challenge to remember*", a "*memory challenge*", or simply "*challenging*".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/elusive

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/challenging

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps saying the data is *boring* or *dull* or *dry* **implies** that it is hard to remember.

> **dry**
>   18. adjective
>   If you describe something such as a book, play, or activity as dry, you mean that it is dull and uninteresting.
>   [disapproval]
>   ...dry, academic phrases.
>   *A lot of the work was very dry and boring in Westminster.*
>
> — https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dry

Answer (score 0):

So, there are some [synonyms of the word **abstruse**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/abstruse), (= 'difficult to comprehend', [from Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstruse)) which might include what you're looking for:

> Perhaps [**esoteric**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/esoteric) will do the trick? When used broadly, as in bit *b* of *definition 1* on Merriam-Webster, it can mean 'difficult to understand.'

Or,

> The first definition of [**Recondite**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recondite) on M-W is 'difficult or impossible for one of ordinary understanding or knowledge to comprehend.'

Or, for something a little less *esoteric*, how about a simple:

> [**Complicated**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complicated), which can mean 'difficult to analyze, understand, or explain, definition 2.

I know that your request is inclined more towards 'difficult to remember', but since understanding and memory intermingle, I wager that these words could work in the provided circumstance.

Alternately, I like @Gustavson's 'memory-demanding.' Let me know if my efforts helped some.